# cannot get default profile on Mac 10.6 to work on AD

Tags: mac, active-directory

Created a default user profile on an intel Mac running 10.6, this works fine locally when new accounts are created. ( ran Repair Disk Permissions, over written the default user profile on the Mac with my own).

The problem I am getting is when I connect the Mac to a Microsoft AD

The settings within the Directory Utility are

Create Mobile account - switched off - don't want
Force local home directory - switched off - want users home directory on AD
Use UNC path - switched on - set to smb
Default user shell- set to /bin/bash

This all connects fine, when a user logs onto a Mac the default user profile I created is not used.

A totally different profile is shown, do I have to copy the default user profile I have created on to the AD ?

or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You are very close to the answer, but simply, you need to create the user in the AD and then login to the mac using the account you created on the AD. If you need to transfer data, fine, but you are totally ok as you are connecting a mac that is not "a true object" in the AD.

I have been using more than 400 macs on the AD and this works great, but without central management and so on. For more advance control within your AD and all macs you can add install additional solutions that will enable more control :

http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/networking_security/admitmac.html

http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/networking_security/centrifysuite.html

You can also check this information to help you on other levels of integration :

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2008.12.interacting.aspx

http://www.seminars.apple.com/contactme/pdf/L334436B_ActiveDirect_WP.pdf

Come back and tell us if it works all out!

Comment: Many thanks for the info, looks like it could be an issue with the AD user account.  When I login using a AD account the local profile I created on the mac is shown now :) but a question mark shows up on the link to the users home directory.  So one step at a time :)  thanks again.. Phil

Comment: Great for the follow-up Phil, tell us what you found!

Comment: Hi well, my first mac lab of computers connected to a mac server and AD working fine :), The main problem as stated above was when a user logged onto any mac using a AD user account the default user profile was not used, the only way I found to fix this problem was to set - system preferences/accounts/login options/network account server edit\choose AD and open directory utility, click on AD and open the advanced option and click the Force -local home directory on startup disk- with this option clicked every thing works, local and ad accounts now show the correct default profile when created.